# Convergence of an infinite product (2)

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, infinite-product

Consider this infinite product: $$\prod _{n=1}^\infty \Bigl( 1+ \frac z n\Bigl) e^{-\frac z n}\ .$$ I must show that it converges to an entire function $f$, and determine the zeros of $f$. It's immediate that $f$ will vanish only in the points $\{-n:n\in \mathbb Z^+\}$, since $f(z)=0$ if and only if one of the factors vanishes in $z$. The problem is to prove that the product actually converges to an entire function, i.e. that it converges uniformly over any compact set of $\mathbb C$.

First off, it's necessary to prove pointwise convergence: as $n\to \infty$ we have $$\Bigl( 1+ \frac z n\Bigl) e^{-\frac z n}-1 \sim \Bigl( 1+ \frac z n\Bigl)\Bigl(1-\frac z n+\frac {z^2} {2n^2}\Bigl)-1=-\frac {z^2} {n^2} +\frac {z^2} {2n^2}=\frac {z^2} {n^2}\ .$$ This proves pointwise convergence for every $z$ (I didn't write the $o\bigl(\frac {z^2} {n^2}\bigl)$ that clearly converge too).

In order to prove uniform convergence over a generic compact set, say $A\subset \mathbb C$, let's define $M=\sup _A|z|$ and $m=\inf_A |z|$. We have $$\Bigl| \Bigl( 1+ \frac z n\Bigl) e^{-\frac z n} -1 \Big|\le  \Bigl( 1+ \frac M n\Bigl) e^{-\frac m n} -1 \le  \Bigl( 1+ \frac M n\Bigl) \Bigl(1-\frac m n + \frac {m^2} {2n^2} \Bigl) -1\ .$$ However here it remains the term $\frac {M-m} n$, so we can't say that the sum converges. How do I avoid this problem? The chain of inequalities above is the only one that seems possible to me, so clearly I am missing something. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is not true that $|e^{-\frac  z n}| \leq e^{-\frac m n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequalities are not valid. You are treating complex numbers the same way you treat real numbers. You cannot use $m$ to bound $e^{-\frac   z n}$.

Actually your argument for pointiwise convergence almost gives uniform convergence on compact sets: The Taylor expansion that you have used actually shows that $|1-(1+\frac z n) e^{-\frac  z n}| \leq \frac C {n^{2}}$ for some constant $C$ whenever $|z|$ is bounded. So M-test finishes the proof.

Comment: Yes, actually I should have used $m=\inf _A \Re (z)$ to bound $e^{-\frac z n}$; however I'm not sure to understand why I can just use M-test in the Taylor expansion above. It is because, in a compact set, $\frac z n $ converges uniformly (as a succession) to $0$, and so the argument of the exponential goes to $0$, right? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Dorian Note that $\inf |z|$ and $ \inf \Re z$ can be $0$. So there is no point is using $m$; it doesn't give anything useful.  Can you prove the inequality I have stated in my answer?  Once you prove that you get uniform convergence.

Comment: Yes, I understand that in this exercise there is no point in using $m$, in fact I tried to understand your method. However, I was saying that in general, in a compact set $A$, it's true that $|e^z| \lt e^m$, with $m=\inf _A \Re (z)$

Comment: What I said in my first comment should prove that in a compact $A$ the term of our series is asymptotic to $\frac {z^2} {n^2}$; then if we put $M=\sup_A |z|$ we obtain that the series is bounded from $\frac {M^2} {n^2}$, and this satisfies Weierstrass criterion.